# Child component remains the same as a parent Angular routing

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing

Learning angular routing, added two routerLinks to parent component, looks like routing is done well, but page remains the same. [Parent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rHQ7R.png)  [Child](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K4Pfk.png)

```
const childrenRoutes: Routes =[
  {path: 'overview', component: AutocompleteOverviewComponent},
  {path: 'api', component: AutocompleteApiComponent}
]

const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '', redirectTo: 'autocomplete', pathMatch: 'full'},
  {path: 'autocomplete', component: DashboardComponent, children: childrenRoutes},
];
```

Comment: have you added `router-outlet` inside the html also is your parent component directly calling the child component?Please add more code

Comment: `<router-outlet>
<a routerLink="overview">OVERVIEW</a> 
<a routerLink="api">API</a> 
</router-outlet>`

Comment: why do you put link inside router outlet?

Answer (score 0):

To make this work you need a `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in your base component and another `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in `DashboardComponent` where you can provide the links outside the router outlet tag